# zerocoin ZKSoK Pedersen commitment process

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I am studying the [zerocoin paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/SP.2013.34)‡. More precisely I am stuck at [page 6](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/%7Erich/class/cs293b-cloud/papers/zerocoin.pdf#page=6), on the Spend function (in paragraph *"B. Our construction"*).
I am not understanding how the ZKSoK is computed.
Let's consider the Pedersen commitment as
$$C\gets g^Sh^r\bmod p$$

I've found a lot of examples online but they all refer to a case where the "secret" is $ω$: $x=g^ω$ And $x$ is public. I understand the steps in this cases but I am not sure about two things on zerocoin:

1. Does the provider give $S$ ($S$=serial number) to the verifier, in order to be able to do the verification?
2. What is the condition that says if the proof is valid or not?

---

‡ Paywalled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, the value $S$ is public. From the notation on page 5, "All values not enclosed in ()’s are assumed to be known to the verifier." This makes sense in the scheme, since, once a coin is spent, its serial becomes public and cannot be used again.
2. You can make efficient ZKPs for a wide range of linear relations about the exponents of some group elements with known bases. [Camenisch and Stadler](https://www.research-collection.ethz.ch/bitstream/handle/20.500.11850/69316/eth-3353-01.pdf) is the usual paper cited here (and in fact, is cited on page 5). Another, perhaps more easy to understand one is by [Maurer](https://crypto.ethz.ch/publications/files/Maurer09.pdf).

Comment: I still do not understand how $S$ is involved during the generation of the proof. More precisely, referring to the example 1 of the Camenisch and Stadler paper, I do not understand where to use it.

Comment: Example 1 doesn't have the form of a Pedersen commitment. It's $g^x$ rather than $g^x h^y$. Example 4 is closer to what you want. [This other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81236/question-of-proving-the-opening-of-pedersen-commitment) specifies the Pedersen opening protocol directly.

Comment: I've seen the answer and I get it, but what prevents an attacker from properly compute zkp and then provide another $S$? How is the proof and $S$ linked together, and how is $S$ correctness verified by the verifier?